# How should I construct this ID class? - JAVA

Tags: java, class, uml

I'm unsure how I should make the `ID` class for `findById`, where `User` is a simple POJO, with username, password, userid, firstname and lastname, a constructor and some getters/setters.

I've already created the interface/classes for the rest, it's just this `ID` class that is stumping me.

***Edit:***

Mansi's replies helped a lot, thanks!

**UML diagram:**

[image]

Comment: https://www.netsurfingzone.com/jpa/spring-data-jpa-crudrepository-finbyid/

Comment: `findById(Id id)`. I think you only need to pass the id of the user which has any datatype like integer, Long, etc.

Comment: `Id` type is currently not defined by the UML you gave us (any implementation could be thinkable), but worst, the way `Id` and users are linked to each other is not specified.

Comment: Is there a class definition of Id or requirements? Usually Id is a Long variable

Comment: Your diagram is no valid UML. The chosen connectors are meant for profile definition only.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

The `Id` just abstracts the type that is used for the identifier `id`.  You could imagine that it's an integer, a string, or any more complex class such as a [UUID/GUID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html).

If you want to show it in your diagram, you'd represent it as a `<<datatype>>` or an ordinary class,  and add a dependency from `Searchable` to this class:

[image]

### But this diagram needs rework

First of all, this diagram is incorrect: interfaces can inherit from other interfaces, but the arrow head must be hollow and not plain.  Classes can realise interfaces, but then the arrow head must still be hollow and the arrow line must be dashed:

[image]

With this corrected, we could imagine that a `UserRepository` inherits from `Searchable`, `Persistable` and `Removable`, since it can search, persist and remove items.

But the design is not very useful,  because the inherited classes are all defined assuming that the item is a `User`. So these basic interfaces are only useful for a user repository.  Consider either to renaming the basic classes to show that they are related to users.  Or, better, consider template interfaces to make it more general:

[image]

Note that the parameters to the operations should also have the form `parameter-name : type-name`;  UML syntax is not Java syntax.